# GNU find: Disable the error when 'find' finds no matches

Tags: linux, find, gnu

I've got a setup where I need to use 'find' to find 0 or more files in a certain directory, however, 'find' always produces an error when there are no files that match a certain check. Is it possible to run 'find' while having it omit errors when no files match the pattern?

Comment: GNU `find` does not report such errors by default, at least not on my systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @grawity said find isn't expected to report these errors. Anyway if you want to suppress error output redirect stderr to /dev/null:

```
find  . HERE_YOUR_FIND_PARAMS 2&> /dev/null
```

One typical case in which find write to stderr happens when there is a directory in your find searching sub-path that hasn't the permission to be opened.

Comment: Why do use `2&>` instead of `2>`?

Comment: Not really a full solution because the exit code will still be 1 instead of zero, likely to break scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The only working solution I found so far was:

```
find something 2&> /dev/null || true
```

This assures that final exit code is zero even when there are no matches and also hides the stdout errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just ignore the errors?  Or, more specifically, redirect them to `/dev/null`?

Comment: I'm using the results in a script, so no, I can't just ignore the errors. Redirecting stderr to /dev/null works, however.